# Listening to multiple port with server using the same Thrift interface

Tags: java, thrift

Is there a way to listen on multiple ports using one Thrift server application?
The Thrift interface would be the same, I just need to distinguish where the client call came from (different implementation of a client).

I plan to use TThreadPoolServer and based on which port the call came from, I want to use different logic.

Limitations:

- I can't change the Thrift interface
- I can't touch the clients, only which hosts and ports they should use

I only find solutions for creating several services with the same server. This is not the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up two Thrift server instances binding the respective ports and of course at least two threads, one per socket.